How should I show that $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+\frac{ac}{b^2d^2}(b^2-a^2)(d^2-c^2)u=0$?
Consider the system of equations $\frac{dx}{dt}=(a-by)x(1-x^2), 0<x<1, \frac{dy}{dt}=-(c-dx)y(1-y^2), 0<y<1$, where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are positive constants. By expanding the system about the fixed point $(x, y)=(\frac{c}{d}, \frac{a}{b})$, show that $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+\frac{ac}{b^2d^2}(b^2-a^2)(d^2-c^2)u=0$, for small $u=x-\frac{c}{d}$, and also show that the period $T$ of small oscillations about this centre is $T=\frac{2\pi bd}{\sqrt{ac(b^2-a^2)(d^2-c^2)}}$.
Here's my work:
Proof:
Let $x=\frac{c}{d}+u$ and $y=\frac{a}{b}+v$.
By direct substitution of $x=\frac{c}{d}+u$ and $y=\frac{a}{b}+v$ into the system, we have $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}=(a-b(\frac{a}{b}+v))(\frac{c}{d}+u)(1-(\frac{c}{d}+u)^2)=-bv(\frac{c}{d}+u)(1-(\frac{c}{d}+u)^2)$ and $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dt}=-(c-d(\frac{c}{d}+u))(\frac{a}{b}+v)(1-(\frac{a}{b}+v)^2)=du(\frac{a}{b}+v)(1-(\frac{a}{b}+v)^2)$.
Above is my work/proof so far. What should I do from here in order to show that $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+\frac{ac}{b^2d^2}(b^2-a^2)(d^2-c^2)u=0$?

Now you expand and keep only the terms that are linear in $u$ or $v$. Then elimininate $v$.

By expanding, I've got $\frac{dx}{dt}=-bv(\frac{c}{d}+u)(1-\frac{c^2}{d^2}+\frac{2c}{d}u+u^2)$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=du(\frac{a}{b}+v)(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{2a}{b}v+v^2)$. What should I do from here?

@Moo, I double checked the question again and it still says the same. May you please mention what's wrong in the signs of $(d^2-c^2)$? Anything wrong in my work above after I expanded those terms?

We have
$$\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}=(a-b(\frac{a}{b}+v))(\frac{c}{d}+u)(1-(\frac{c}{d}+u)^2)=-bv(\frac{c}{d}+u)(1-(\frac{c}{d}+u)^2)\\ \dot{y}=\frac{dy}{dt}=-(c-d(\frac{c}{d}+u))(\frac{a}{b}+v)(1-(\frac{a}{b}+v)^2)=du(\frac{a}{b}+v)(1-(\frac{a}{b}+v)^2)$$
Expanding the first equation
$$\dot{u} = \frac{b c^3 v}{d^3}+\frac{3 b c^2 u v}{d^2}+\frac{3 b c u^2 v}{d}-\frac{b c v}{d}+b u^3 v-b u v$$
Expanding the second equation
$$\dot{v} = -\frac{a^3 d u}{b^3}-\frac{3 a^2 d u v}{b^2}-\frac{3 a d u v^2}{b}+\frac{a d u}{b}-d u v^3+d u v$$
Keeping only linear terms
$$\dot{u} = \left(\frac{b c^3}{d^3}-\frac{b c}{d}\right)v \\ \dot{v} = \left(\frac{a d}{b}-\frac{a^3 d}{b^3}\right)u$$
We now eliminate $v$, so take the derivative of the first equation and substitute in the second
$$\ddot{u} = \left(\frac{b c^3}{d^3}-\frac{b c}{d}\right) \dot{v} = \left(\frac{b c^3}{d^3}-\frac{b c}{d}\right)\left(\frac{a d}{b}-\frac{a^3 d}{b^3}\right)  u$$
Simplifying
$$\ddot{u} = \dfrac{ac}{b^2d^2}\left(b^2-a^2\right) \left(c^2-d^2\right)u(t)$$
Rearranging
$$\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2} +\dfrac{ac}{b^2d^2}\left(b^2-a^2\right) \left(d^2-c^2\right)u(t) = 0$$

Everything is correct. I doubled checked on everything, especially the algebra part of the work, it took a while because the algebra part was very tedious to check/verify. You just had a typo at the end where $u(t)=u$ instead of $\frac{du}{dt}$. Thank you so much for your help as it made perfect sense now!

@Purity: You are welcome and I corrected the typo. Regards.

May you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977758/how-should-i-show-that-the-system-dotx-yy-x-doty-x2-has-no-limit-cy ?

Due to the factors $u$, $v$ in front of the right sides, one can treat any additional occurrence of $u$, $v$ in these expressions as $0$, so that only the constants remain. An expansion (before that simplification) is not really required here, contrary to what I previously said. But in general it would be the systematic approach.
